# Distinguish between multiple edge colliders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject with multiple EdgeColliders2D attached because during run-time I change my sprite in the SpriteRenderer component attached to the same GameObject at multiple instances.

I want to be able to distinguish between these multiple EdgeColliders2D either programmatically or via Inspector window. The thing is, had it been a simple CircleCollide2D, I could programmatically change the radius of CircleCollider2D via script, but I don't know how to change the vertices of the EdgeColliders2D in the script because if that could happen then I can totally avoid having multiple EdgeColliders2D attached to the GameObject at the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than switching sprites and colliders on the same game object, consider having multiple child game objects, each with a sprite and corresponding collider, and dynamically switch between which one would be active at given time. It will both help to keep the code simpler, and make the job of level/game designers in the scene view easier.